# Preorder and relation to Inorder Traversal

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, inorder

I find that if we have Preorder and Inorder Traversal, we have a unique tree.

can i conclude:

For Each Preorder Traversal, we have multiple Inorder Traversal. this is True or False Conclusion? every one would help me and add some detail.

thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because from a single preorder sequence you can create multiple trees. For instance: [4,3,1, 2] can be repesented as a tree with root 4, children 3 and 2. Then you can insert 1 as either left or right child of 3. Depending on where you will insert it the inorder sequence will change.

You can also reason about it in this way: you have **n** numbers, with them you can get **n!** permutations. Generating a tree from your traversal would be possible if the number of permutations was equal to the number of possible trees you can create usin those **n** numbers. This is not the case, though as you can for instance create many trees, where every node has only a left child or only a right child, this gives you 2*n! and there are more so there has to be a permutation that can generate more than 1 tree => more than 1 inorder traversal.

This is of course true in general case, BSTs have a unique inorder sequence.

Comment: so we can say, one Preorder is correspond to one inorder is false?

Comment: In general case, yes. If we are talking about BSTs then 1 preorder corresponds to exactly 1 inorder.

Answer (score 0):

True,
for example:
given a preorder traversal
abdec

```
      a
     / \
    b   c
   / \
  d   e
```

---

many inorder traversals are possible:
baedc,
dbeac
and so on...